# Move HTML checkbox to left hand side of it's width

Tags: html, css, checkbox, css-float, forms

I cannot use any JavaScript and **would like an answer in just CSS** if possbile. I have the following check box in a form:

```
<label for="autologin">Remember Me</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="autologin" name="autologin" value="1">
<div class="clear"></div>
```

with the following CSS:

```
label {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 0px;
}

input {
    float: right;
    margin: 5px 0px;
    width: 200px;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

What CSS can I add to the check-box to make it appear on the left hand side of its 200px width? I'm having a bit of a hard time with floats (vertical alignment in particular) but I hear it's the correct practice.
[image: chrome showing check box width]

EDIT: OK so a lot of people are suggesting not floating the inputs to the right. If so I may as well not use float at all and just set the width of the label and have a 
 after each line. Would this be acceptable practice or am I just miss-using floats here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this , here's the demo [link](http://jsfiddle.net/sourcecode/sHfDq/)

```
label {
    float:left;
    margin: 5px 0px;
}

input {
    // float right;
    margin: 5px 0px;
    width: 200px;

}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 19):

Don't 'move it to the left of its width' - let it dictate its own width and then add padding on the right side if you need it. But judging from your design, you don't.

`input[type=checkbox] { width: auto }`

Answer (score 16):

I think the problem that cause your checkbox to be center like that because you set the input `width:200px` so all you need to do is to add the `width:auto` to your checkbox by its id(autologin). Also you need to create a div container for your check box. Here is the HTML:

```
<label for="autologin">Remember Me</label>
<div id='check'><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="autologin" name="autologin" value="1"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

and here is the CSS:

```
label {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 0px;
}

input {
    float: right;
    margin: 5px 0px;
    width: 200px;
    border:solid 1px;
}
#autologin
{
width:auto;
float:left;
}
#check
{
float:right;
width:200px;
border:solid 1px;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

Hope this help :)

Answer (score 1):

You should remove `float: right;` and `width: 200px;` in your `input` class declaration. And I would set widths for all labels (i.e. 200px) to align the second column.

```
label {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 0px;
    width: 200px; 
}

input {
    /*float: left;*/   /* This will also work. */
    margin: 5px 0px;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

See **[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/pZRJQ/)**.

Answer (score 0):

A table is fine for this, since you have (user-supplied) tabular data. This will solve your vertical alignment issues too.

Unfortunately you can't put the checkbox on the left side of its width. Personally, I would recommend avoiding styling `input` without specifying `[type=something]`. However, if you use a lot of HTML5 input types such as `email`, `number`, `url` etc then you may find it useful to style all `input` one way, then use `width:auto` for `[type=radio]` and `[type=checkbox]`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using float attribute means, you have to provide a width to the form container.

Answer (score 0):

You can't align or change a checkbox's direction, because it has no attachment, it's just a box.

In order to get this done simply put it in a div and give the div this style:

```
.checkDIV
{
    text-align:left;
}
```

example:

```
<div align="center" class="checkDIV">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="autologin" name="autologin" value="1">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Set its width to like 20px, that fixes the problem. It doesn't need to be 200px does it?